# moment isBetween include from and to dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to filter an array and get data between two dates. What I've done does not give me the data on `fromDate` or `toDate`.

```
  $scope.visitorFilterByDate = function(fromDate, toDate, array, arrayCopy, searchArray){
    debugger
    $scope[array] = $scope[arrayCopy].filter(function(v){
      debugger 
      return moment(v.visit_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
             .isBetween(moment($scope[fromDate], 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 
                           moment($scope[toDate], 'DD-MM-YYYY'), null, []);
    })
    $scope[searchArray] = angular.copy($scope[array]);
  }
```

Comment: which moment version are you using?

Comment: @VikashSingh 2.18.1

Answer (score 0):

`isBetween` function takes only string formatted dates as arguments, so you should covert it to string using `format` function like this:

```
 moment(moment(v.visit_date).format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
         .isBetween(moment($scope[fromDate]).format('DD-MM-YYYY'), 
                       moment($scope[toDate]).format('DD-MM-YYYY'), null, [])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer man, but it turns out there was an other cdn link to moment 2.9 below the 2.18 one. I removed it and it works now